# Highcharts X-Axis value not completely displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

when I try to view my chart, all data on the x-axis are not displayed.
Here an exemple: http://jsfiddle.net/zn4y45pL/

```
options.xAxis.categories.push(this.innerHTML);
alert(this.innerHTML);
```

This shows me all the data.

Any ideas on what's the problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating for each of the points separate series. Instead, create one series and push points to `data` array:

```
        // the data series
        options.series = [{
            name: this.innerHTML,
            data: []
        }];
        $init('td', table).each(function (j) {
            options.series[0].data.push(parseFloat(this.innerHTML));
        });
```

And demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zn4y45pL/2/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are only pushing one category to the options.xAxis.categories array.

```
$init('tbody th', table).each( function(i) {
            options.xAxis.categories.push(this.innerHTML);
        });
```

Try debugging this .each in dev tools and make sure it iterates for each category you are expecting to display in your highchart's xaxis.
Specifically, make sure 'this' is in the context you are expecting per iteration.

Comment: I try this but .each loop on all my categories and this.innerHTML contains labels I want to display.